# mod_rewrite and Dynamic Directory Structure

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm building a page admin in php and have a function that lets me make pages children of other pages.  With a recursive function (based on who is a parent of who) I end up with a list of links like:

```
<ul class="navList" id="navList">

   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/Home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/About">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/Links">Link Page</a>

   <ul>

      <li><a href="http://mysite.com/Links/PHP_Links">PHP Links</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://mysite.com/Links/JQuery_Links">JQuery Links</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://mysite.com/Links/Contributors">Contriubutors</a>

      <ul>

         <li><a href="http://mysite.com/Links/Contributors/Blog">Blog</a></li>

      </ul>

      </li>

   </ul>

   </li>

   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>

</ul>
```

So, you can see it's possible to end up with multiple directories.  Now, my question is, how do I anticipate and handle this with mod_rewrite?  I've got a script I use for a situation where the directory might be just one level deep, but anything past one directory will just reroute to the home page as an error...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ index.php?category=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=home
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?page=home
```

I'm supposing this is sort of a logic question.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so, writing it out here seemed to help.  This is what I did...

I changed my mod_rewrite to send me the whole string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.*]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Then in my php I explode $page with '/'

```
$dirStructure = explode('/',$page);
```

So if the url were to be Links/Blog/Thoughts I'd get an array I could sort through like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Links
[1] => Blog
[2] => Thoughts
)
```

I can then just look for my page that corresponds with the last element of the array.

Comment: +1 for letting PHP handle the more complex job, resulting in a much more maintainable system. I usually forgo setting an arbitrary GET variable and use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` directly though, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: .. with the proper RewriteCond !-f & !-d of course, otherwise it's a hell of a job to get to actual files :)

Comment: @wrikken, I like forgoing the arbitrary. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to do this by hand :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2&subpage=$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ index.php?category=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```